# Using a set statement to select many files with a pattern

Tags: sas, proc-sql, datastep

I am trying to load in a large number of data sets that have a similar pattern to their naming in a set statement ie

```
data output;
     set &filenames. ;
```

I have seen in other questions a method of creating a macro with all of the names using a `proc sql` statement but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I was wondering if someone could help me to construct this `proc sql` code. The naming pattern is something like `abcXX03` where `abc` is common and the `XX` is changing **(ie it can be `XX XY or XZ` say) but I only want to select the ones with the patern `abcXX03`.** I've tried something like

```
proc sql;
 select memnames into :names
    separated by " " 
       from dictionary.tables
         where libname eq "LIBNAME" and 
         memname like "%XX03"
quit;
```

based on previous answers.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: What is the naming pattern ?

Comment: The pattern is something like abcXX03, abcXY03, abcXZ03 (more combos though) and I only want to select abcXX03.

Comment: That is not a clear pattern. Please explain in more detail. Is DCFXX03 a valid data set name, or is it ABCXX05?

Comment: Hopefully this is clearer. The issue I have is that the common part of each file name is the beginning `abc`. The ending varies between `03` and `05` and the middle has 50 potential values so I cannot use a colon. So the file names I want are something like `abc**03` where ** is changing, but there also files like `abc**05` that I do not want. In this case, I want to select all files with this `abc**03` pattern.

Comment: So ABCXY03 is ok? From your previous response it's not but it would meet the criteria you just mentioned. At this point, I probably won't spend more time on this issue. If your matching criteria is complicated, I would suggest pulling all the names into a data set from sashelp.vtable, writing a filter condition to pick the ones you want and then creating a macro variable from there.

Answer (score 4):

Use the colon short cut. This will APPEND all the data sets into the same file

```
data want;
set abc: ;
run;
```

Comment: I see, I forgot to mention this, the pattern XX is not the same for every file and I only want the pattern to be XX say instead of XY.

Comment: Why can't you change that to `set abcXX: ;` then? As long as the prefix is uniquely identifiable taht should work. If it's not and you don't say that, there's no way I can know that.